# Показывать блоки по клику на кнопку по несколько штук

Tags: javascript

Есть код (`javascript`). В нем сейчас реализовано: показ блоков с шагом в 5 `div`-ов при клике на кнопку с `id` `#more_comments_sidebar`. У меня не получается реализовать: кнопка с `id` `#more_comments_sidebar` должна прятаться, когда все `div`-ы отображаются.

Сейчас реализовано так, когда кнопка с `id` `#more_comments_sidebar` прячется, показывается кнопка с `id` `#reset_comments_sidebar` и на оборот. Можно реализовать, что при нажатии кнопки с `id` `#reset_comments_sidebar` все `div`-ы прячутся кроме первых пяти?

```js
let data = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#add-shesht-comment-template-sidebar .shesht-comment-template-sidebar')),
  reset_comments = document.querySelector('#reset_comments_sidebar'),
  more_comments = document.querySelector('#more_comments_sidebar'),
  step = 5,
  item = 0;

data.slice(step).forEach(e => e.style.display = 'none');
item += step;

document.querySelector('#more_comments_sidebar').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let tmp = data.slice(item, item + step);
  tmp.forEach(e => e.style.display = 'block');
  item += step;

  if (tmp.length < 5) {
    more_comments.style.display = 'none';
    reset_comments.style.display = 'block';
  }
});

document.querySelector('#reset_comments_sidebar').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  more_comments.style.display = 'block';
  reset_comments.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```css
#reset_comments_sidebar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="add-shesht-comment-template-sidebar">
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">1</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">2</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">3</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">4</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">5</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">6</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">7</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">8</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">9</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">10</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">11</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">12</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">13</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">14</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">15</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">16</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">17</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">18</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">19</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">20</div>
</div>
<button id="more_comments_sidebar" class="more_comments_btn_sidebar">Показать ещё</button>
<button id="reset_comments_sidebar" class="more_comments_btn_sidebar">Скрыть</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала нужно починить отображение кнопок.
Лучший вариант это делать проверку на то, сколько отображается сейчас и меньше или равно ли это число чем всё кол-во элементов.
Для этого я изменил условие `tmp.length < 5`, на `item >= data.length`

Далее, для "сброса", нам нужно вернуть это всё в изначально состояние.
Получается скрываем все блоки, кроме первых пяти (`data.slice(step).forEach(e => e.style.display = 'none');`)
И возвращаем переменную для подсчёта в то состояние, которое оно было при инициализации (`item = 0; item += step;` я заменил на просто `item = step`), ну и меняем состояние кнопок.

```js
let data = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#add-shesht-comment-template-sidebar .shesht-comment-template-sidebar')),
  reset_comments = document.querySelector('#reset_comments_sidebar'),
  more_comments = document.querySelector('#more_comments_sidebar'),
  step = 5,
  item = 0;

data.slice(step).forEach(e => e.style.display = 'none');
item += step;

document.querySelector('#more_comments_sidebar').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let tmp = data.slice(item, item + step);
  tmp.forEach(e => e.style.display = 'block');
  item += step;
  
  if (item >= data.length) {
    more_comments.style.display = 'none';
    reset_comments.style.display = 'block';
  }
});

document.querySelector('#reset_comments_sidebar').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  data.slice(step).forEach(e => e.style.display = 'none');
  item = step;
  more_comments.style.display = 'block';
  reset_comments.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```css
#reset_comments_sidebar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="add-shesht-comment-template-sidebar">
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">1</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">2</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">3</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">4</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">5</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">6</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">7</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">8</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">9</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">10</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">11</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">12</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">13</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">14</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">15</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">16</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">17</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">18</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">19</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">20</div>
</div>
<button id="more_comments_sidebar" class="more_comments_btn_sidebar">Показать ещё</button>
<button id="reset_comments_sidebar" class="more_comments_btn_sidebar">Скрыть</button>
```

Comment: Минус без причины - признак дурачины. Пишите хоть за что минус.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const comments = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#add-shesht-comment-template-sidebar .shesht-comment-template-sidebar'));
const step = 5;
let item = 0;

function toggleCommnts() {
  item += step;
  comments.forEach((element, index) => {
    element.style.display = index >= item ? 'none' : '';
  });
}

more_comments_sidebar.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  toggleCommnts();
  if (item >= comments.length) {
    more_comments_sidebar.style.display = 'none';
    reset_comments_sidebar.style.display = 'block';
  }
});

reset_comments_sidebar.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  item = 0;
  toggleCommnts();
  reset_comments_sidebar.style.display = '';
  more_comments_sidebar.style.display = '';
});

toggleCommnts();
```

```css
#reset_comments_sidebar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="add-shesht-comment-template-sidebar">
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">1</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">2</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">3</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">4</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">5</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">6</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">7</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">8</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">9</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">10</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">11</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">12</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">13</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">14</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">15</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">16</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">17</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">18</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">19</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">20</div>
</div>
<button id="more_comments_sidebar" class="more_comments_btn_sidebar">Показать ещё</button>
<button id="reset_comments_sidebar" class="more_comments_btn_sidebar">Скрыть</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let data = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#add-shesht-comment-template-sidebar .shesht-comment-template-sidebar')),
  reset_comments = document.querySelector('#reset_comments_sidebar'),
  more_comments = document.querySelector('#more_comments_sidebar'),
  step = 5,
  item = 0;

data.slice(step).forEach(e => e.style.display = 'none');
item += step;

document.querySelector('#more_comments_sidebar').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let tmp = data.slice(item, item + step);
  tmp.forEach(e => e.style.display = 'block');
  item += step;

  if (item >= data.length) {
    more_comments.style.display = 'none';
    reset_comments.style.display = 'block'; // Закомментить если надо: кнопка с id #more_comments_sidebar должна прятаться, когда все div-ы отображаются
  }
});

document.querySelector('#reset_comments_sidebar').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  more_comments.style.display = 'block';
  reset_comments.style.display = 'none';
  let afterFive = document.querySelectorAll('.shesht-comment-template-sidebar:nth-child(n+6)');
  afterFive.forEach(e => e.style.display = 'none');
  item=step;
});
```

```css
#reset_comments_sidebar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="add-shesht-comment-template-sidebar">
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">1</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">2</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">3</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">4</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">5</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">6</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">7</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">8</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">9</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">10</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">11</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">12</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">13</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">14</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">15</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">16</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">17</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">18</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">19</div>
  <div class="shesht-comment-template-sidebar">20</div>
</div>
<button id="more_comments_sidebar" class="more_comments_btn_sidebar">Показать ещё</button>
<button id="reset_comments_sidebar" class="more_comments_btn_sidebar">Скрыть</button>
```

Comment: Считаю что бессмысленно набирать ещё коллекцию элементов, только ради того, чтобы отделить элементы через CSS